# jquery callback issues

Tags: jquery, callback

I need to make the 'content' div animate after the inner divs fade out. The `fadeOut` animation worked before I added the callback though. Can someone tell me what I messed up on the callback function?

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').click(function() {
        $('#topcontent,#bottomcontent').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('#content').css({
                position:'relative',
                background-color:'black'
            }).animate({
                height:$(window).height(),
                width:$(this).width()
            },400);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'wrapper'>
        <div id = 'content'>
            <div id = 'topcontent'>
            TOP<br />
            </div>
            <div id = 'bottomcontent'>
            BOTTOM
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the .css() call...
`background-color:'black'` should be `background: 'black'`

or as is pointed out in the comment "background-color": 'black'

Comment: or `"background-color":"black"` - it's the hyphen in an unquoted key that causes the syntax error.

Comment: It should probably be `backgroundColor`, not just `background`, since that's the property used in the question.

Comment: If there are other `background-*` properties on the element your solution will overwrite them.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#content').css({
    position:'relative',
    'background-color':'black'
})
```

The `-` character is an operator for subtraction in JS, which isn't valid here (even if you were trying to subtract numbers). Wrapping the property in quotes gets around this issue.

Comment: Or `backgroundColor` to save 3 characters :)

Comment: True, I just felt that explaining casing in JS vs CSS would be out of scope of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead.

```
backgroundColor:'black';
```

or as David suggested

```
'background-color':'black'
```